# Intellij equivalent to Source lookup path in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I would like to know if anyone has an idea on what is the equivalent to Eclipse *Source lookup path* in the application *run configuration* in Intellij.

Because I'm trying to migrate a project from eclipse to Intellij and I absolutely need this option for it to work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the `Run/Debug Configurations` dialog, you'll see `Use classpath of module`. IntelliJ will include the source from that module in the classpath for that run/debug process.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]